# Is there a possibility in R to fill a histogram with a loop?

Tags: r, loops, histogram

In a simulation I produce one very large vector of numbers, which I want to show in a histogram. Unfortunately, my RAM doesn't allow vectors as long as I require them to be. (10^10 entries)

Thus, I put my simulation in a loop producing several smaller vectors of shorter length.

It tried the hist-function and the summation of hist$counts, however the binning keeps changing, which makes a summation impossible(for me...)

Now, I search a soultion to handle these smaller vectors, in sequential way.

1. read the frist vector (from the loop)
2. extract information for a histogram
3. keep the histogram information of the 1st but discard the vector itself to safe memory
4. do this for all the other vectors and store only the histogramm of all vectors.
5. build one histogram where the accumulated histogram information are added up to one set of information.

Can any one help out? Is this possible in R ?  I'm stuck...  Thanks to all who took time to read this !

Answer (score 2):

Your problem, if I understand correctly, is that the histogram bins are changing. So the natural solution would be to fix the bins using the `breaks` parameter of the `hist` function. For better performance you can set `plot = FALSE` and just collect the bin counts from each part.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the information an histogram will require with the function `count()` of the library **dplyr**.

Let's say the values of vector of numbers range from 1 to 100. First you have to define your buckets : 1-10, 11-20, ...

Then, within the loop and with a smaller vector, use the function `cut()` with the arguments `breaks =` to transform your numeric vector to a categorical vector. Use count to count the numbers of values in each buckets.

At the end of your loop, combine all the counts you obtain.